# How can I write this in nifty way rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Right now I have this code:
`@category.name.gsub(' ', '-').gsub('--','-').gsub('--','-')`

What id does:
If I have category with name `sometext sometext`, it will change all space charactes to `-` dash characters. `sometext-someteext` ( I use this for url building)

`.gsub('--','-').gsub('--','-')` - this part I need for the case when name is something like 
`sometext - sometext` so without this part my method will give me wrong output like `sometext---sometext`

So what is a more elegant way to rewrite that 3 gsubs into one?

Answer (score 0):

Regex to the rescue:

```
.gsub(/ \-+ /, ' - ')
```

Comment: Can you explain it?=)

Answer (score 0):

ActiveSupport::Inflector contains [parameterize](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html#method-i-parameterize) which is a more general for building urls.

```
> 'sometext - sometext'.parameterize
=> "sometext-sometext"
```